# How to schedule a Cronjob so it executes all R scripts in a file

Tags: r, bash, cron, cron-task

I want to schedule a cronjob so it executes every R script I put into a certain directory.

From another post on this site I've seen the following code:

`0 0 * * * cd /home/script2; Rscript scriptSecos.R >/dev/null 2>&1`

This would run the RScript `scriptSecos.R` from the path `/home/script2`.

What would I need to change in order to run every single script in `/home/script2`? Should I simply omit the `scriptSecos.R`?

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat crude solution would be to use the `find` shell command to list all files in a given directory with names matching the pattern `"*.R"` and then pipe `|` that list of files into `xargs`, which then executes the `Rscript` command once for each file in the list. *(This is why the `-n 1` command line flag is necessary)*

```
find /home/YourDirectory/ -name "*.R" | xargs -n 1 Rscript
```